# Create PDF in PHP without manually creating HTML

Tags: php, pdf-generation

Can we really generate pdf files using php thro' some APIs without manually creating HTML. Beacuse I have got to create Invoices for some 50 groups and each having different HTML, so it would be a pain to create HTML for each of them and then create PDF using library from this HTML. Is there any other way?

Comment: share what you have achieved

Comment: What are the differences between the invoices?

Comment: yes, it is : [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Comment: you could use something like http://pdfmyurl.com/?url=https://www.weburl.com -- i use this on my companies website

Comment: Can i create a template and then generate a pdf where everything would be programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

yes of course, start learning from

> http://www.fpdf.org/ or
>   https://tcpdf.org/

It will definitely helps you

Comment: Vishal, Can i create a template and then generate a pdf where everything would be programmatically?